# Large org-mode file causes error "Re-entering top level after C stack overflow"

Tags: org-mode, undo-tree-mode

I use org-mode quite a lot and of late I have noticed one of my larger org-mode files has caused Emacs to throw this error:

```
Re-entering top level after C stack overflow
```

I tried debugging using the usual debugging mechanisms, including debugging a single function [1] but I could not get any additional information on the problem. Note also that I used the file for a very long time without seeing any problems, and I have much larger org-mode files which do not suffer from this issue.

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273546/emacs-how-to-see-how-to-debug-a-single-elisp-function-emacs-command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end, the solution to all my woes was as per this reddit question [1], which I quote verbatim:

> What ultimately fixed it was deleting the unto-treehistory file corresponding to the Org file I was trying to open. The history file itself was a good 280k, probably the largest of all of my undo tree history files. I periodically commit my Org changes to Git, so having that whole history stored is not even providing any value in the long-term, so deleting it was no problem.

I addressed my issue by first disabling `undo-tree-mode`, at which point I could use Emacs normally again including saving the file. I then found the undo-tree file by looking at the messages buffer, where you should see something like:

```
Wrote /tmp/.!home!${VERY_LONG_PATH}!${FILE_NAME}.org.~undo-tree~
```

You can safely delete this file and re-enable undo-tree and Emacs should return back to normal.

[1] https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/9fs8pp/reentering_top_level_after_c_stack_overflow/

Comment: This sounds like a bug in `undo-tree`. Please consider [sending a bug report](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/UndoTree).

Comment: @NickD -- I have bug reports from years ago on this issue 27571 and 27779 ... `npostavs` wrote up a test to reproduce the issue ... and there was some development by the Emacs team to fix this, but I did not spend any time testing the potential fix ...  I presently use a Frankenstein version of Emacs that reverts certain code that caused this issue, and I launch Emacs from the terminal after issuing the command `ulimit -S -s unlimited`